# Recursively chain specific values together without passing an array by reference

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Imagine the following multi-dimensional array:

```
$a = array(
  'key' => 'hello',
  'children' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'sub-1'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'sub-2',
      'children' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'sub-sub-1'
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I require a function that recursively runs through such an array and then finally returns a chain of all the values of a certain sub-key, using a glue string.

```
function collectKeyChain(array $array, $key, $parentKey, $glue){
  foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if(is_array($v[$parentKey]))
      $children=self::collectKeyChain($v[$parentKey], $key, $parentKey, $glue, $out);
    $chain[]=$glue . implode($glue, $children);
  }
  return $chain;
}
```

Called this way:

```
collectValueChain($a, 'key', 'children', '/');
```

Should then return this:

```
array(
  'hello',
  'hello/sub-1',
  'hello/sub-2',
  'hello/sub-2/sub-sub-1'
)
```

Unfortunately my brain seems completely unable to perform the task of "nested thinking". The code provided in the function above doesn't work, simply because it makes no sense. I can either use the recursive function to return an array or a string. But in the final output i require an array. On the other hand i need to chain the elements together.

That's the dilemma. And the only solution that came up in my head was using another parameter, that is passed by reference, which is an array that is being filled with the results.

Like this:

```
collectValueChain($a, 'key', 'children', '/', $arrayToBeFilledWithResults);
```

But i was unable to make even this work without getting into using multiple functions.

Perhaps it just cannot be done more easily, but i would still like to find out.

Comment: I implement your second sugestion using a variable to store the value, it is the second answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function collectKeyChain(array $array, $key, $parentKey, $glue) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == $key) {
            $base = $v;
            $return[] = $base;
        } elseif ($k == $parentKey && is_array($v)) {
            foreach ($v as $_v) {
                $children = collectKeyChain($_v, $key, $parentKey, $glue);
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $return[] = $base . $glue . $child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Note that if this is to be a static method in a class you have to add self:: to the recursive method call.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what i was looking for! Thank You!

Comment: Your function works very well. Aside from being ashamed for not having been able to write it myself, i discovered that it will refuse to provide any results when confronted with an array that's nested on the first level. I am trying to adapt it.

Comment: If you mean that you're passing something like array($a) to collectKeyChain(), then that should not be handled by the function, but where the function is called. That way you keep the function clean of unnecessary logic. You could write a separate cleanKeyChainArray() for that, for example.

Comment: Yep, i was getting there. Funny enough, i tried feeding it with `reset($array)` followed by `$array=$array['children']` and that's why it couldn't work. Of course, once i just fed it with the `reset($array)` it worked optimally. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple version, without lots of foreach. Consider the second approach:

```
collectValueChain($a, 'key', 'children', '/', $arrayToBeFilledWithResults);
```

I do this:

```
function  collectValueChain($a, $keyname, $parent, $glue, &$rtn, $pre="") {
  $_pre = "";
  if ($a[$keyname]) {
    $rtn[] = $_pre = $pre.$glue.$a[$keyname];        
  }
  if ($a[$parent]) {
    if(is_array($a[$parent])) {
      foreach($a[$parent] as $c)
        collectValueChain($c, $keyname, $parent, $glue, $rtn, $_pre );
    } else {
      collectValueChain(a[$parent], $keyname, $parent, $glue, $rtn, $_pre );
    }
  }
  $qtd = count($rtn);
  return $rtn[-1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution!